# Randomly selecting specific rows in R data

Tags: r, excel, random

I'm wondering if it's possible to randomly select specific categories from rows of a excel spreadsheet in R.

E.g. here is sample data
[sample data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fzC4n.png)

I want to randomly select only one type of the "Station" rows (e.g. only the 'LC04' rows, but have this determined randomly). Is there a way this can be done in R? I have a large dataset, and want to randomize the selection ~100 times, so then I can use each random outcome for additional analyses.

Thanks!

Comment: Using `filter` from the {dplyr} package, could you do: `filter(mydata, Station == sample(unique(mydata$Station), 1))` to select the rows by a random `Station`?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

Using the `group_by` and `sample_n` function from the dplyr library

```
newdata <- sampledata %>% group_by(station) %>% sample_n(2)
```

The `sample_n` value can be modified according to the required number of rows of each type of station